# Setting up NTP service to Automatic restart

Tags: linux, ntp, runlevel, ntpd

Setting up `NTP` service to Automatic restart which one should set to `on` in given
list

```
ntpd 0:off  1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ntpd** is an example of a daemon, sometimes called a *service* in come circles.

Run levels are not connected to the idea that if you shut down a daemon like **ntpd**, a second watchdog service will turn it back on. 
If  what you mean by "Automatic restart" is "turn on a daemon after it has died by accident," I recommend you look at [watchdog](https://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog) or something similar.

You can also set up a daemon to start when a machine boots up.  This is often accomplished using run levels.

In the example you have provided you have listed **ntpd** and the seven  run levels:

```
ntpd 0:off  1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

In the example **ntpd** is currently off.  It will not start at any of those run levels.

The numbers 0 through 6 refer to [runlevels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel).  As the machine enters a run level, services at that run level are started.

The `runlevel` command will give you first the previous run level, then the current run level.  (It will on CentOS and Ubuntu, at least).

```
[centos@ip-10-100-3-23 ~]$ runlevel
N 3
[centos@ip-10-100-3-23 ~]$
```

This command shows that this machine is currently at run level 3.

The way to change the run level depends on which OS and which version of that OS you are running.  For CentOS 6, the command `chkconfig --level 3   ntpd on` will turn on ntpd to start at run level 3.  In the example below, I configure **ntpd** to start on entering run level 3.  I then revert that change and turn it off.

```
[root@host ~]# chkconfig --list ntpd
ntpd            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
[root@host ~]# chkconfig --level 3   ntpd on
[root@host ~]# chkconfig --list ntpd
ntpd            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:off   5:off   6:off
[root@host ~]# chkconfig --level 3   ntpd off
[root@host ~]# chkconfig --list ntpd
ntpd            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
[root@host ~]#
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Typically ntpd is run at runlevels 2, 3, 4 and 5. If you just use `chkconfig ntpd on` to set it on for these default runlevels.